# Difference between Makefile and zsh

Tags: ls, make

I'm trying to create Makefile rule:

```
dev:
  ls {web,src}/**/*.* | entr make run-build
```

And there is different behaviour between using `make dev` and using this command direct. Do you have idea what's the reason?

I have `iTerm2` with `zsh`on `OSX El Capitan`

Comment: "And there is different behaviour". A little more specificity about the different behaviours would be helpful. As things stand, the question is less than clear.

Comment: `make` typically runs `/bin/sh` and not some other shell by default, and `/bin/sh` probably isn't `zsh`.

Comment: Different behaviour means, `entr` have problem with tracking edited files. When I'm running `ls` command from `make` without `entr` part it returns the same files but combining these commands together it behave different.